# BeautifulSoup Not Finding All 'th'

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm currently trying to scrape a statistics site in Python 3.7 using BeautifulSoup. I'm trying to grab all of the headers from a table as my column headers, but for some reason BeautifulSoup isn't grabbing all of the headers that are located within the 'th' tags.

Here is my code:

```
url = 'https://www.eliteprospects.com/team/552/guelph-storm/2005-2006?tab=stats'
html = urlopen(url)
scraper = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
column_headers = [th.getText() for th in scraper.findAll('tr', limit=1)[0].findAll('th')] # Find Column Headers.
print(column_headers)
```

Here is the output I am getting:
['#', 'Player', 'GP', 'G', 'A', 'TP']

Here is the output I should be getting:
['#', 'Player', 'GP', 'G', 'A', 'TP', 'PIM', '+/-', 'GP', 'G', 'A', 'TP', 'PIM', '+/-']

For Reference here is what the table source html looks like:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sortable skater-stats highlight-stats" data-sort-url="https://www.eliteprospects.com/team/552/guelph-storm/2005-2006?tab=stats" data-sort-ajax-container="#players" data-sort-ajax-url="https://www.eliteprospects.com/ajax/team.player-stats?teamId=552&amp;season=2005-2006&amp;position=">
                <thead style="background-color: #fff">
                    <tr style="background-color: #fff">
                        <th class="position">#</th>
                        <th class="player sorted" data-sort="player">Player<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></th>
                        <th class="gp" data-sort="gp">GP</th>
                        <th class="g" data-sort="g">G</th>
                        <th class="a" data-sort="a">A</th>
                        <th class="tp" data-sort="tp">TP</th>
                        <th class="pim" data-sort="pim">PIM</th>
                        <th class="pm" data-sort="pm">+/-</th>
                        <th class="separator">&nbsp;</th>
                        <th class="playoffs gp" data-sort="playoffs-gp">GP</th>
                        <th class="playoffs g" data-sort="playoffs-g">G</th>
                        <th class="playoffs a" data-sort="playoffs-a">A</th>
                        <th class="playoffs tp" data-sort="playoffs-tp">TP</th>
                        <th class="playoffs pim" data-sort="playoffs-pim">PIM</th>
                        <th class="playoffs pm" data-sort="playoffs-pm">+/-</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source of the page you are trying to scrape, this is exactly what the data looks like:

```
    <div class="table-wizard">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="position">#</th>
                    <th class="player">Player</th>
                    <th class="gp">GP</th>
                    <th class="g">G</th>
                    <th class="a">A</th>
                    <th class="sorted tp">TP</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
```

That is why that is the only data you get. It's not even a case where JavaScript alters it after the fact. If I perform a `querySelector` in the browser console, I get the same thing:

```
> document.querySelector('tr')
> <tr>
      <th class="position">#</th>
      <th class="player">Player</th>
      <th class="gp">GP</th>
      <th class="g">G</th>
      <th class="a">A</th>
      <th class="sorted tp">TP</th>
  </tr>
```

In short, Beautiful Soup is giving you exactly all the `th` tags in the first `tr` tag.

If you try and grab the second `tr` tag that has `th` tags using the CSS selector `tr:has(th)`, you will see you get more `th` tags:

```
column_headers = [th.getText() for th in scraper.select('tr:has(th)', limit=2)[1].findAll('th')]
```

Output

```
['#', 'Player', 'GP', 'G', 'A', 'TP', 'PIM', '+/-', '\xa0', 'GP', 'G', 'A', 'TP', 'PIM', '+/-']
```

Comment: Thank you @facelessuser. Your explanation was really helpful, although I found it odd that in Chrome's 'inspect' option it was all be listed in the same 'tr' tag

Answer (score 0):

Since the tag is `<table>`, let pandas do the work for you (it uses bs4 under the hood). Then you can do easy manipulation if needed:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.eliteprospects.com/team/552/guelph-storm/2005-2006?tab=stats'
dfs = pd.read_html(url)

headers = list(dfs[1].columns)

print(headers)
```

**Output:**

```
print(headers)
['#', 'Player', 'GP', 'G', 'A', 'TP', 'PIM', '+/-', 'Unnamed: 8', 'GP.1', 'G.1', 'A.1', 'TP.1', 'PIM.1', '+/-.1']
```